# Passing Data between sibling components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to pass data between two sibiling components and the component structure looks like below. I need to pass the data between two sibling components,

I dont want to make the component to be parent child instead I need to pass the data between sibling components

But when the button is clicked I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'settDate' of undefined

Not sure if we are missing anything here

Comment: My first thought would be. Either use a shared service. Or emit information from each sibling via `Output()` to the parent component (PRJ Shipping Component), and then send that information back down from the parent to each sibling respectively.

Comment: Here is an article that might be helpful if using the shared service route. https://dev.to/avatsaev/simple-state-management-in-angular-with-only-services-and-rxjs-41p8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your components are under same parent, I assume `PRJ Shipping Component` is a SMART component and the rest are DUMB components (they only interact with Input and Output)

So you need to add an Output to `reportingFilterComponent` and emitting the filter value, then `PRJ Shipping Component` has event handler to get the value, and pass it as Input to `tjl shipment component` something like below

reportingFilterComponent.ts

```
@Output() filterChange : EventEmitter<ShipDateFilterModel[]> = new EventEmitter<ShipDateFilterModel[]>()

filterButtonClick() {
  this.filterChange.emit(/. your filter value../);
}
```

PRJ Shipping Component.html

```
<app-reporting (filterChange)="onFilterChange($event)"></app-reporting>

<app-tjl-shipment [filter]="filter"></app-tjl-shipment>
```

PRJ Shipping Component.ts

```
filter: ShipDateFilterModel[];

onFilterChange(event:ShipDateFilterModel[]) {
   this.filter = event;
}
```

tjl-shipment.component.ts

```
@Input() filter: ShipDateFilterModel[];

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

  if (changes.filter && changes.filter.currentValue) {
     // do whatever is needed
  }
}
```

### Improvement

For keeping the DUMB component DUMB, they shouldn't do any  http call or something. so being said it better to `PRJ Shipping Component` receives the filter value and do the filter operation and just passing filtered data to `tjl-shipment.component`

### Another solution

You can create a service to keep the data between components and informing the changes, but in your case it's a `needless complexity`

Comment: I get the the error` 'Output' accepts too few arguments to be used as a decorator here. Did you mean to call it first and write '@Output()'?` When I tried to declare the Output

Comment: Do I need to declare filterChange with in button tags?

Comment: @trx `@Output()` is correct, pay attention I wrote the whole code here to you get the idea, may be some syntax error in other parts as well

Comment: filterChange is needed to declare in the `reportingFilterComponent.ts` component, you just emit it in the button click